# How to resize webpart in SharePoint Online Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powerbi

I met the following situation, I'm trying to embed Power BI report to a SharePoint Online page, I managed to do that by using Power BI webpart as it shown bellow :

[image]

now I wonder if there is a way to resize this webpart (change the width of the webpart), because it looks too small and the report appears very small to the end users.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using one-column layout in your page or anything else??

Comment: Yes i am, one-column layout

Comment: Have you set any frame size to your report from power BI? Also, are you sure you are using full width one-column layout section for your SharePoint page? because Power BI tile is working fine for me on SharePoint page with full page width.

Comment: In your screenshot, it appears it is already as wide as the page, you cannot get any wider in a modern page, it is designed to be responsive so that there is never horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, I resized the page size in Power BI Desktop, and in SPO, i'm using One-column layout section for SP page

Comment: @willman, it's just my screen is big, i will edit the post and put a new screenshot from my normal screen

Answer (score 1):

You can set the frame size to '16:9' or '4:3'.Apart from the mentioned frame size , you cannot configure the webpart frame size according to your screen.

Please look into below Power BI webpart issue that has been raised to Microsoft

[Microsoft Forum](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/32077330-set-frame-size-in-sharepoint-web-part)